# How do I import an existing Grails 3 (3.0.12) project in IntelliJ 15

Tags: intellij-idea, grails-3.0, intellij-15

There's documentation on IntelliJ's website for creating a new Grails project, but importing a project is more sketchy and I cannot get it to work for me.

If I tell IntelliJ to import a new project, and point it to my project directory, it does not recognize it as a Grails project. After the project imports, I can go to the Project menu, right click on the project and go to "add Framework support..." and select Groovy, but IntelliJ still does not recognize my project as a Grails project. For instance, with a new Grails project the run menu would contain a button for running the app that would be decorated with the 3-cups icon synonymous with Grails. I don't get that with my imported project.

Here are the precise steps I'm taking so far:

1. Start with my fresh unimported project. This is a project and I can build manually using grails compile.
2. Open IntellliJ 15 UE and select "**Import Project**"
3. Select the top level directory containing my build.gradle file and grails-app directory
4. Select **Create project from existing sources**
5. Default project name/location
6. Select all source directories that were found. These include:

   1. **grails-app** conf, controllers, domain, init, taglib directories
   2. src/main/groovy
   3. test/unit
7. At the **Libraries** screen, go with the default gradle-wrapper option
8. At the **Modules** screen go with the 3
9. "Select project SDK..." I select my 1.8 JDK setup. There's no mention of Grails here.
10. I see a **"No Frameworks detected"** message. Should I be able to configure Grails here?
11. Select finish.

At this point I'm at the IntelliJ editor window with a project that doesn't build. I can go to "Add Frameworks Support" and enable support for Groovy and at that point reference my Grails SDK. But in any case I feel like I shouldn't have to do this. I think IntelliJ ought to be able to detect my Project type and characteristics and that I'm just not configuring it right.

But regardless, my project still doesn't compile inside IntelliJ. I have to build it via the console. Right now none of my Java files located in src/main/groovy compile. All of the imports that references `org.springframework` are coming back with the "cannot resolve symbol" error.

Comment: Yes, I tried all this yesterday, my comment is below but it didn't help. It happened on my computer after I upgraded to 3.0.12. But on my macbook it happened after upgrade to 3.0.11. No Intellisense now on both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this issue before as well. The only way around it is to:

- Blow away the intellij project
- Import from Existing Sources
- Double click the build.gradle
- Ensure auto-import on gradle is set to false

Here's the IntelliJ issue related - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149513

Comment: After that you will get a gradle project, not grails. After you navigate to some groovy files IDEA asks about groovy libs and it is all. Now I have a gradle project, everything work fine, but there is no code navigation inside grails libs, I spent an hour trying to add libs manually, a framework suppurt and SDK but it does't help. There is no way to add Grails support to the project. On the other hand if I create new grails project then methods like domainClass.save() are highlighted but all libs through gradle are missing.

Comment: So I need to make refresh via gradle tab and make them included in project but adter that things become vice versa - all libs are ok, but no grails code Intellisense.

Comment: erich's fix was good enough in that I could build and run my project, but there are still inconsistencies. When I go to the run menu, I do see a Grails launch task, but for some reason I can't execute a debug for this. Bottom line- IntelliJ's implementation of grails 3 is still lacking. Hopefully we will hear from a JetBrains rep to explain the status of this

Comment: I spent many days but succeed to launch integration tests with debugging.

Comment: For debug use gradle. Launch a "run" task from a gradle panel. After that it will be added to run menu. For integration test right click on the test file and choose "create testName".

Comment: I did as erichelgeson told, but I still do not have Intellisense. When I do "import project" thre is a choice "create project from existing sources" and "import project from external model" and many sub options. I tried all...

Comment: I do get it intellisense in grails with this(GORM, etc), also I just use the bootRun grade task to debug and run.

Comment: I can also run a debug, but still cannot get IDE support and Intellisense. But before 3.0.12 I had. Some people have the same problem.