# How to Import existing Grails app into Intellij

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, import, intellij-14

I'm having a hard time importing an existing Grails 3 application into Intellij, in what feels like the "right way". I have the looked through the official intellij documentation but haven't found much to help me (what I have found hasn't fixed any of my issues). It's possible that I simply didn't find what I needed. [This post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981134/how-do-i-import-an-existing-grails-3-3-0-12-project-in-intellij-15) doesn't quite help me out either.

Here's what I've tried:

**Note:** The application I'm importing is grails 3.1.9 and works fine using the Grails CLI.

1. Import the project on build.gradle

   I get the following errors/warnings:

`Warning:<i><b>root project 'app': Unable to build Grails project configuration</b>
Details: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileCopy'.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: A conflict was found between the following modules:
 - jline:jline:2.12
 - jline:jline:2.11</i>`

`Warning:<i><b>root project 'app': Unable to build Grails project configuration</b>
Details: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileCopy'.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: A conflict was found between the following modules:
 - jline:jline:2.12
 - jline:jline:2.11</i>`

However if I ignore those warnings, I can get the application to run by using a gradle run/debug configuration, using bootRun. If I try to setup a run/debug with Grails, intellij doesn't let me pick an "application". Adding Grails as a framework does not change this behavior. I'm also missing some of the grails specific features that Intellij gives you.

2. Create the project from existing sources

Following this series of menu's, I have no idea what to pick. With the defaults that Intellij selects, I am still unable to set a Grails run/debug configuration. I assume I just have to select the right sources, but I have no idea what I should be selecting.

If someone could give me a list of steps to perform, or point out exactly where I need to go in the documentation, that would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks for the video, very clear instructions. After some tinkering, I was able to get it to run from the init/application.groovy file (the second method shown I was already doing). However I still don't have access to some of the features from Intellij (Ex. right clicking the controller folder and being able to create a controller under the new tab). I was still getting those jline warnings as well. I'm also still unable to select Grails as a run/debug configuration, Intellij lists it as "irrelevant". If I create a new Grails app through Intellij everything works. Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose there must be something wrong with my project, because it does look like I'm importing it in the correct way, so I would say the video link answers my SO question, though it doesn't exactly solve my current situation.